# how to make only one USB port visible for an application

Tags: c#, usb

im developing a C# application which needs to connect with multiple usb devices and i want the application to be able to see one usb port at a time but not stop connections or power to the port.
does anyone have any idea what i can use or do?

Comment: define "one usb port at a time"

Comment: say i have 4 usb ports in my pc. i want the application to be able to see only one of those ports and whatever device is connected

Answer (score 1):

USB follows a tree topology. Every connection in a USB chain has a path associated. You can filter that, i.e. hide all the entries not in the path you want to make visible. So:

- enumerate the USB devices connected
- remove all devices not on your choosen path from the list
- show the list to the user

Comment: how can i implement this in c#?

Comment: @JonathanElhalal: The programming language doesn't matter. What matters is, which operating system do you use. I guess Windows. Frankly I cannot give you a full introduction into the API here, because it's just too complex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538930(v=vs.85).aspx look for device enumeration. The rest is up to you, which means: Take the values given back to you from the API and apply comparisons to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SetupAPI to select which device you want to talk to and then open a handle to the specific device.  Once you have the handle open, you will only be talking to one USB device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791(v=vs.85).aspx

SetupAPI is quite complicated but you can find example C# code online from Jan Axelson:

http://www.lvr.com/winusb.htm

Comment: i already have a way to talk to a specific device. my problem is my application only finds the first device connected so if start the listen function again and make only one usb port visible i would solve my problem

Comment: "my problem is my application only finds the first device connected"  <-  If you learn more about SetupAPI or whatever library you are using, you should be able to select the device to talk to based on certain criteria, like the serial number or USB port.  If you provide more specific details about what tools you are using I might be able to give more specific advice.